# How can I merge 2 tables having one common column into one table?

Tags: google-sheets

I have 2 tables on different sheets.

Table #1 has columns:

- Fruit
- Size
- Color

Table #2 has columns:

- Fruit
- Price
- Currency

I wanna have a table #3, where I would have automatically and always up-to-date columns:

- Fruit
- Size
- Color
- Price
- Currency

By always up-to-date I mean that if I update data in table #1 or table #2 - table #3 would automatically sync with them.

To explain better here is a [demo spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1h9Na-EuToSf_qftmbToIJIfsqU413Db7rRrixuqsIfU/edit#gid=191425206)

How can I achieve this?

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Hzlk8LMtVfI

Comment: Answer is described in the link below: https://www.ablebits.com/docs/google-sheets-merge-two-sheets/

Answer (score 1):

Try this unique formula (which takes into account the possibilities of differences between the two sheets)

```
=arrayformula({{"Fruit","Size","Color","Price","Currency"};
unique({'Fruit base data'!A2:A4;'Fruit extended data'!A2:A4}),
iferror(vlookup(unique({'Fruit base data'!A2:A4;'Fruit extended data'!A2:A4}),'Fruit base data'!A2:C4,{2,3},0),{"",""}),
iferror(vlookup(unique({'Fruit base data'!A2:A4;'Fruit extended data'!A2:A4}),'Fruit extended data'!A2:C4,{2,3},0),{"",""})
})
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

all you need is:

```
=INDEX(QUERY({'Fruit base data'!A:C, 
      VLOOKUP('Fruit base data'!A:A, 'Fruit extended data'!A:C, {2, 3}, 0)}, 
 "where Col1 is not null", 1))
```

[image]